# Replacing google slides images using slides api in shared google drives

Tags: python, presentation, google-slides-api, google-slides, google-drive-shared-drive

Following up with my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706103/replacing-google-slides-images-using-slides-api) question, now, facing an error when I use `shared google drive` with the `service account` having `Manager` privilege on that shared drive, it is failing during the image replacement in google slides. In addition, using my personal account I can edit any file on that shared drive, with that I have two questions:

1. why slides API's `batchUpdate` method needs public access when used to replace images in slides using `replaceImage` ?
2. what is the difference when interacting with the shared drives with `personal account` and `service account` ?

Any suggestion and help appreciated, note: I am still learning about google API's. Thank you in advance.

used personal account to edit the slides it works.

Comment: About your 1st question of `why slides API's batchUpdate method needs public access when used to replace images in slides using replaceImage ?`, I think that it is due to the specification on the Google side. About your 2nd question of `what is the difference when interacting with the shared drives with personal account and service account ?`, I couldn't understand the 2nd question. Can I ask you about the details of it? If my understanding of your 2 questions, I apologize.

Comment: I have seen this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75731854/google-service-account-that-has-access-to-shared-drives-without-explicit-access) that may give you an idea on your question 2.